# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: deleting current dictionary

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode8

When I try to run the project in Xcode 8.1 , I am facing below error (See logs). I cleaned up the code and did reset the simulator but that didn't work.

```
** Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper resetKeychainItem], /Users/manishpathak/iosProjects/MyProject/MyProject/KeychainItemWrapper.m:202
2017-07-14 15:09:09.521 MyProject[26741:3318830] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Problem deleting current dictionary.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054ba34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104f1b21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054be442 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000104ab1e4d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   AppifyViewer                        0x000000010278b542 -[KeychainItemWrapper resetKeychainItem] + 2354
    5   AppifyViewer                        0x0000000102713494 +[MDXKeychain storeToKeychain:withPassword:] + 292
    6   AppifyViewer                        0x00000001027b3a59 -[MDXSecurityPolicy saveCredential:] + 281
    7   AppifyViewer                        0x0000000102718f37 __32-[MDXLoginViewController login:]_block_invoke + 407
    8   AppifyViewer                        0x000000010285ed19 __76-[RXPromise registerWithExecutionContext:onSuccess:onFailure:returnPromise:]_block_invoke_3 + 89
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108140980 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010816a0cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010814a8d6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 406
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010547e4f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105443f8d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105443494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000109faba6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001067df964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    17  AppifyViewer                        0x00000001027a4857 main + 231
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001081b668d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: In the `Show the breakpoint navigator` click on the `+` button on the bottom left, and add a `Exception Breakpoint`. Run the app and check which line of code is producing the exception.

Comment: Your code (or some code you have included into your project) threw an exception at line 202 of `KeychainItemWrapper`  - look at that code and work out what it is complaining about

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

It's working after Enabling KeyChain Sharing.

**Enable Keychain Sharing**

1- Click `Target`of the project

2- Click on tab `Capabilities` and search `Keychain sharing`.

3- Enable `Keychain sharing`.